# Framework7: Delete items of an array with swipeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, swipe-gesture, html-framework-7

I tried app developing with Framework7.

I print my array (list) in this way:

```
if (list != null){
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    output = output + '<li class="swipeout"><div class="item-content swipeout-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title-row"><div class="item-title">' + list[i].name + '</div></div><div class="item-subtitle">' + new Date(list[i].fDate).toLocaleDateString() + '</div></div></div><div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" class="swipeout-delete">Delete</a></div></li>';
    }
}
$$('#liste').html(output);
```

When I swipeout an entry, the entry will disappear but he is still in the array.

This is to handle the remove-event:

```
$$('.swipeout').on('deleted', function () {
  myApp.alert('Item removed');
});
```

How can I get the index of the element to remove it also from the array?
Alternatively, is there an other way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Markus

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd rather use Framework7's view engine to render the swipeout items and take advantage of the @index helper. [Click here for further information.](http://idangero.us/template7/#.V2AG7bsrIdV)

In your markup, you'd have something similiar to this:

```
<div class="list-block">
 <ul>
{{#each item in list}}
<li class="swipeout">
  <!-- Usual list element wrapped with "swipeout-content" -->
  <div class="swipeout-content">
    <!-- Your list element here -->
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-media">...</div>
      <div class="item-inner">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Swipeout actions right -->
  <div class="swipeout-actions-right">
    <!-- Swipeout actions links/buttons -->
    <a href="#" data-index={{@index}}>Action 1</a>
    <a class="swipeout-close" href="#" data-index={{@index}}>Action 2</a>
  </div>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Notice that I'm using the "each" helper along with "@index" to render the items and put an attribute on them with the id. But you can still achieve the same objective by using the "i" variable inside the for loop:

```
if (list != null){
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
output = output + '<li class="swipeout"><div class="item-content swipeout-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title-row"><div class="item-title">' + list[i].name + '</div></div><div class="item-subtitle">' + new Date(list[i].fDate).toLocaleDateString() + '</div></div></div><div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" class="swipeout-delete" data-index='+i+'>Delete</a></div></li>';
}
```

}

When the event is fired:

```
$$('.swipeout').on('deleted', function () {
  var $thisAction = $(this);

  // Here you delete the item 
  delete list[$thisAction.data('index')];

  myApp.alert('Item removed');
});
```

In this case you can't use Array.slice because if you delete item 2 from the markup, the element with the index 3 will replace item 2. The problem with the above approach is that you have to take care of the "holes" in your array. A much better approach would be to use a two-way binding framework, such as VueJs.